# concatenate variable values in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    XML:
        <Form id="id8" name="1234_A" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Form" subClass="Form">  
          <UserData id="id10" type="Attributes">
            <UserValue value="val1" title="var1"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="val2" title="var2"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="val3" title="var3"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="val4" title="var4"></UserValue>    
            <UserValue value="val6" title="var6"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="val7" title="var7"></UserValue>    
          </UserData>
        </Form>
   XSL: 
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[@title='var1']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var2" select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[@title='var2']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var3" select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[@title='var3']"/>
        <xsl:variable name="var6" select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue[@title='var6']"/>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="String">
            <xsl:variable name="temp" select="concat($var1/@value,',',$var2/@value,',',$var3/@value,',',$var6/@value)"/>
          </Data>
        </Cell>
```

In above XML, i want to get values (var1,var2,var3,var6). Got those values into variables.
Now in XSL i want to concatenate the variable values using a comma separator. But if any of the variable value is empty i'm getting multiple comma's(,,). Basically i have to ignore a variable if its empty. Please help me.
I'm using XSLT1.0

Comment: Before concatenating the variables, may be you can check whether that variable in not null and not empty. Based on that you can concatenate only those variables which are not null and not empty.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Do you really need to use those variables? If you address the original nodes within an `xsl:for-each` instruction, non-existing nodes will be automatically excluded (this is assuming the empty variables are empty because the nodes they refer to do not exist, not because the nodes themselves are empty)).

Comment: hi michael.. i've updated the question. Pls have a look

Answer (score 0):

If the `var1`-`var4` `UserValue` elements are guaranteed to appear in that particular order in the original XML then it's a straightforward `for-each`:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:for-each select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue
       [@title='var1' or @title='var2' or @title='var3' or @title='var6']
       [normalize-space(@value)]">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

(The `[normalize-space(@value)]` predicate excludes any of the target elements that exist but have an empty value).  If it's *not* guaranteed that the var1-var4 order will match document order then you need to use a trick to force the for-each to give you the elements in the right order.

```
<xsl:variable name="ordering" select="'|var1|var2|var3|var6|'" />

<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:for-each select="$ele/plm:UserData/plm:UserValue
       [@title='var1' or @title='var2' or @title='var3' or @title='var6']
       [normalize-space(@value)]">
    <xsl:sort select="
          string-length(substring-before($ordering, concat('|', @title, '|'))"
      data-type="number" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'm having some problem with [normalize-space()] predicate, for-each is not looping for each element. If i remove [normalize-space()] it is executing for all elements.

Comment: @userksp sorry, with the original question lacking an input example I'd missed the fact that the "value" you were talking about was an attribute rather then the element's text content.  This should work better now.